# Match last name using awk

Tags: regex, unix, awk

Say there's a file like this

```
1 | John Smith | 70000
2 | Al McSmith | 60000
```

If I use

```
awk -F"|" '$2~/Smith/' file
```

both rows are matched.

Is there a way to only match John Smith? (USING AWK ONLY)

EDIT: I'm trying to match the people that have Smith as their last name, without matching McSmith, or O'Smith, etc.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: It looks like many of the proposed solutions would match people who have Smith as their middle name, e.g. `D'Arcy Smith Bigglesworth` or hyphenated last names e.g. `Horatio Smith-Nelson` or apostrophied names like `Seamus O'Smith`. Is there some reason names like that (or others) can't be part of your data? You should include any "unusual" names like that that can happen in your sample input/output as well as all possible variations of white space around the names so we can see how they should be handled and you have something to test a possible solution against.

Answer (score 4):

this may work for you:

```
awk -F'|' '$2~/ Smith\s*$/' file
```

it won't match:

```
fooSmith
Smithfoo
foo Smith is middlename
```

Comment: upvote and deleting my similar answer, but mention that `\s` is gawk-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Just stick a Space before `Smith`:

```
awk -F'|' '$2~/ Smith/' testfile
```

If there is a name like `John Smitherton` in there, then stick a space after as well (since it looks like you have `<space><delim><space>` between each field). Otherwise you can get a little fancier with the regex, but your space padding is pretty useful here.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. Just out of curiosity, any other ways to do this? With regex?

Comment: @Kent just posted some fancier regex that will do the trick. Again, though, because you have a space before AND after `Smith` by the way your data is structured, then just `/ Smith /` will work fine. But... @Kent's example is more universal for other folks that might have data structured like `1|John Smith|70000'

Comment: @Tirtha, (GNU?) awk's flavour of regular expressions has word boundary markers: a zero-width assertion where theres a "word character" on one side and a non-word character on the other side. `$2 ~ /\<Smith\>/` -- that will avoid matching "McSmith" however "O'Smith" **will** match. In this case you have to use whitespace to delimit the last name you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've made test. I created file: test.in with your content:

> 1 | John Smith | 70000
>   2 | Al McSmith | 60000

Then tried another expression:

```
 awk -F'|' '{print $2~/\sSmith\s/}'  test.in
```

It prints:

```
1
0
```

So, 1 for Smith, 0 for McSmith.

[UPD] `\s` - is an additional character, specific for `gawk`

Comment: You should mention that `\s` is gawk-specific. You don't need the `(` and `)` btw.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, you're right we don't need patterns here. Rechecked manual for \s.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `grep`

```
grep -E "[^|]*\|[^|]*\<Smith\>"
```

**explanation**

`[^|]` match any character except `|`

`\|` match with `|`

`\<` `\>` start and end of word